# IOS pushnotification using php

Tags: php, ios

I have create pushnotification for ios. Following coding i got from website. And the device token is from Our Apple device that i have changed.

```
<?php
$deviceToken = '0f744707bebcf74f9b7c25d48e3358945fxxx01da5ddb387462c7eaf61bbad78';
$msg_push="hi there";
$deviceToken = str_replace(" ", "", $deviceToken);
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'pushchat';
// Put your alert message here:
$message = $msg_push;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'pushcert.pem');//'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );
// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);
// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
?>
```

The pushcert.pem file i have included in the same folder. Know when i run this page in server i get the msg"Connected to APNS Message successfully delivered". But i don't get the notification message in my apple device. So is any error in this code. What is wrong here?

Comment: did you implement the code from app side..? And if yes then check that they have used the correct certificates..and proper provisioning profile.

Comment: show your remote notification details

Comment: i got it from http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1
this side

Comment: no no this coding is fine what you added for  in app delegate for push notification

Answer (score -2):

It can be because your app is in production environment then you have to remove the sandbox from the 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195'

or

It may be because push notifications are not enabled in the apple account for the particular bundle identifier.It can also be because methods for push notification are not defined in the app.